# An Error while Downloading Android Source code

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to download the android source code and for that I am following official documents provided on [source.android.com](http://ce.android.com/setup/start), using command:

> repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest

and then executed

> repo sync

everything was working fine but at last i got this error:

`Checking out projects:  85% (704/819) platform/prebuilts/go/linux-x86error: Cannot checkout platform/prebuilts/gradle-plugin: ManifestInvalidRevisionError: revision master in platform/prebuilts/gradle-plugin not found 
error: in`sync`: revision master in platform/prebuilts/gradle-plugin not found`

any lead on this is appreciated !! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -rf prebuilts/gradle-plugin/.git.tmp/
# or
rm -rf prebuilts/gradle-plugin/.git/
```